# Who ate more apples than banana?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, having-clause

For the below sample data, please help me to find the person who ate more apples than bananas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/athPR.png)

Like for instance in the attached data image, Jhon and Rita ate more apples than bananas.
I wrote a query for the same but with an inner query. I was thinking about an alternate optimal solution.

```
WITH DATA AS (
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Banana' FRUIT, SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Banana' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Apple' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Apple' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Apple' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Rita' name, 'Apple' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jack' name, 'Apple' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon' name, 'Banana' FRUIT,  SYSDATE eatingTime FROM dual
)
SELECT name FROM DATA p
WHERE 
(SELECT count(*) FROM DATA b WHERE b.FRUIT= 'Banana' AND b.name = p.name) < 
(SELECT count(*) FROM DATA a WHERE a.FRUIT= 'Apple' AND a.name = p.name)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your test data as formatted text in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select name
from data
group by name
having 
    sum(case when fruit = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) 
        > sum(case when fruit = 'Banana' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as GMB says above, you can use aggregation + having.
Another way to do the same would be:

```
select name
from data d1
group by name
having 
    (select count(fruit) from data d2 where d1.name = d2.name and fruit = 'apple')
        > (select count(fruit) from data d2 where d1.name = d2.name and fruit = 'banana');
```

Comment: Doable but costly creating subqueries.